# How to disable django registration password help_text

Tags: python, django

I am new in Django,I have a Django registration page for New users,I and I need  to disable the password and username and help_text.I have read through some similar questions about disabling the help_texts but none seem to disable the password help_texts.

Here is my code :

```
class CustomUserCreation(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField()
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username','email','password1','password2',]
        help_texts = {
            'email' : None,
            'username' : None,
            'password1' : None,
            'password2' : None,

        }

class UpdateUser(forms.ModelForm):
    email = forms.EmailField()

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['email','username',]

class UpdateProfile(forms.ModelForm):
    profile_picture = forms.ImageField()
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ['profile_picture',]
```

and my init

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django import forms

class UserCreateForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(UserCreateForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        for fieldname in ['username', 'password1', 'password2']:
            self.fields[fieldname].help_text = None

print UserCreateForm()
```

Answer (score 0):

I will rewrite your classes now,,,

## 1)

```
class CustomUserCreation(UserCreationForm):
    ''' avoid help_text with email, username, password1, password2 (As you want)'''
    email = forms.EmailField()

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = (
            'username',
            'email',
            'password1',
            'password2'
        )

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CustomUserCreation, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        for field_name in ('username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2'):
            self.fields[field_name].help_text = ''
```

## 2)

```
class UpdateUser(forms.ModelForm):
    email = forms.EmailField()

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['email','username',]

class UpdateProfile(forms.ModelForm):
    profile_picture = forms.ImageField()
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ['profile_picture',]
```

## 3)

```
class UserCreateForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(UserCreateForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        for field_name in ('email', 'username', 'password1', 'password2'):
            self.fields[field_name].help_text = ''
```

`help_texts` attribute in `class Meta` is responsible to `override` `help_text` for fields, which is generated from `Model` (When using `ModelForm`). In your case use override `__init__` and read fields directly (all field, does not matter it's generated from `Model` or are just attribute of `Form` are populated in `self.fields` instance attribute which represents `OrderedDict`) and then override `help_text` for each field is really good idea.

Hope, it helps you.

Comment: Thank you very much gachdavit,for your useful help,it worked like a charm.Its a life saver